# Alternator motor on 3 phase power

Tags: alternator

Hi was wondering would a alternator work as a motor if supplied dc power to the rotor and 3 phase ac to the stator. Have seen a lot of posts and videos turning it into a bldc motor but none on turning it into a 3 phase motor and would doing so overheat the rotor of a alternator?

Comment: In this instance  Bldc is a three phase motor. Running it with an ESC (electronic speed controller) means you can vary the speed, but if you had 3phase AC at the correct voltage it would work as well. The alternator knows no difference. Would the rotor overheat? Depends how much current you put through it. The alternator will have a power limit due to heating of the windings etc and how much temperature rise / cooling it has. Duty cycle also comes into play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible to operate an automotive alternator as a synchronous motor. However most synchronous motors do not inherently develop significant starting torque if started at full voltage and frequency. They either have induction motor features built into the rotor or they are started with a variable frequency drive (VFD). Since an automotive alternator doesn't have motor starting features, you would probably need a VFD. It may be somewhat difficult to estimate suitable operating parameters and ratings, but it should be possible to do that.

Answer (score 3):

It could, yes. You would have to remove the internal rectifier diodes and connect directly to the windings. And you would have to supply it with low voltage AC power. As long as the voltage is sufficiently low, and the load is not excessive, the alternator will not burn up.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did this experiment and used 12 V battery for rotor magnetisation. Stator I fed 48
V through BLDC controller (which it would hv converted into 3 phase AC) the alternator did run like a motor! But the torque was not sufficiently high. Next I am going to try 110 V 3 phase AC to stator coils.
Hopefully it should yield higher torque like a BLDC motor.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/348729)